# How can I set positions of nodes or get required orientation to draw graph using graphviz in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx, graphviz

I am new to creating graphs in Python. I am trying to create a simple logic tree using graphviz library in Python.

The code I used is as follows

```
import graphviz

h = graphviz.Digraph(filename = "output/logictree.gv")

#Nodes
#Red boxes
h.attr('node', color='red', shape = "box" )
h.node(name = "a", label = "Emissions Intensity (gCO2/vkm)")
h.node(name = "b", label = 'Load Factor (pkm/vkm)')
h.node(name = "d", label = "Activity per capita (pkm/capita)")

#Blue boxes
h.attr('node', color='blue', shape = "box" )
h.node(name = "c", label = "Emissions Intensity (gCO2/pkm)")
h.node(name = "f", label = "Emissions per capita (gCO2/capita)")
h.node(name = "g", label = "Total Emissions (gCO2)")

#Yellow box
h.attr('node', color='yellow', shape = "box" )
h.node(name = "e", label = "Population")

h.edge("a","c")
h.edge("b","c")
h.edge("c","f")
h.edge("d","f")
h.edge("e","g")
h.edge("f","g")

h.view()
```

The output I get is as shown:
[image]

This is indeed my desired output, however, I'd like to set the position of nodes to make it horizontal orientation.

I am able to set the desired position using networkx package, but I don't get the required node attributes for different nodes in networkx.
The code I use to get graph from networkx is as follows:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph(filename = "logictree.gv")

G.add_nodes_from([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

pos = {0:(0,50),
      1:(0, 0),
      2:(25, 25),
      3:(25, -25),
      4:(50, 50),
      5:(50, 0),
      6:(75, 25)}

G.add_edges_from([(0, 2), (1, 2), (2,5), (3,5), (4,6),(5,6)])
labels = {}
labels[0] = "Emissions Intensity\n(gCO2/vkm)"
labels[1] = "Load factor\n (pkm/vkm)"
labels[2] = "Emissions Intensity\n (gCO2/pkm)"
labels[3] = "Activity per capita\n (pkm/capita)"
labels[4] = "Population"
labels[5] = "Emissions per capita\n(gCO2/capita)"
labels[6] = "Total emissions\n(gCO2)"

plt.figure(figsize = (20, 8))
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos = pos, node_shape = "s", labels = labels,
                bbox = dict(facecolor = "white"))
```

and the graph is as shown[image]

How can I set the position of nodes or get similar orientation for the graph created using graphviz in Python?

Comment: Native Graphviz does allow explicit positioning of nodes (and edges), but I doubt you need it here.  If you want left-to-right instead of top-to-bottom, the rankdir attribute (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/rankdir/) will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, to rotate the graph you can use the attribute [`rankdir`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/rankdir/) with value `LR`. If you need to change the order of the nodes to keep the `Population` node at the top, you must also add the attribute [`ordering`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/ordering/) with value `in`.
Part of script:

```py
import graphviz

h = graphviz.Digraph(filename = "output/logictree.gv", format='svg',
                     graph_attr=dict(rankdir='LR', ordering='in'))
...
```

Result:
[image: horizontal graph made with graphviz python package]

About desired positions in NetworkX, you can also set it using Graphviz package, with attribute [`pos`](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/neato_no_op.html?highlight=pos#neato-no-op-flag) and set attribute `engine` to [`neato`](https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/neato/) (which can proccess `pos`, unlike the default `dot` [layout engine](https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/)):

```py
import graphviz

h = graphviz.Digraph(filename = "output/logictree.gv", format='svg',
                     engine='neato')

h.attr('node', color='red', shape = "box" )
h.node(name = "a", label = "Emissions Intensity (gCO2/vkm)", pos='0,50')
h.node(name = "b", label = 'Load Factor (pkm/vkm)', pos='0,0')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is controlled by *rankdir* attribute which you can apply to the graph. It forces the direction of node layout to be one of 4 choices

- TB (top to bottom; default)
- BT (bottom to top)
- LR (left to right) <-- I believe this is what you want
- RL (right to left)

given you are using *networkx* library. Here is the syntax:

```
G = nx.DiGraph(filename = "logictree.gv")
G.graph['graph']={'rankdir': 'LR'}  # apply the preferred rankdir
```

Graphviz Docs: https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/rankdir/

Reference posts:
[How to add dot's graph attribute into final dot output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885986/how-to-add-dots-graph-attribute-into-final-dot-output)
[How to draw trees left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69439468/how-to-draw-trees-left-to-right)